# How to generate dictionaries from multiple lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following lists :

```
valuevalues = [4, 5, 35, 23, 16, 7, 12]
labelvalues = ['john', 'joe', 'Pier', 'Paul', 'Moe', 'Jane', 'Ruth']
labels = ['label' for i in range(len(valuevalues))]
values = ['value' for i in range(len(valuevalues))]
```

And I would like to generate the following dictionaries:

```
[{'label': 'john', 'value':4},
 {'label': 'joe', 'value':5},
 {'label': 'Pier', 'value':35},
 ...
 {'label': 'Ruth', 'value':12}]
```

Which kind of loop or function Should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and the following comprehension:

```
[{"label": l, "value": v} for l, v in zip(labelvalues, valuevalues)]
# [{'label': 'john', 'value': 4}, {'label': 'joe', 'value': 5}, 
#  {'label': 'Pier', 'value': 35}, {'label': 'Paul', 'value': 23}, 
#  {'label': 'Moe', 'value': 16}, {'label': 'Jane', 'value': 7}, 
#  {'label': 'Ruth', 'value': 12}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
[{labels[i]:labelvalues[i],values[i]:valuevalues[i]} for i in range(len(valuevalues))]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's generally considered to be a good thing to post your attempt first.

Anyway, what you are looking for is:

```
result = [{'label': label, 'value': value} for label, value in zip(labelvalues, valuevalues)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the solution. My attempts were too far from the solution to be interesting...

Comment: Still you could post just to let people know you've tried. Or maybe they will be able to guide you, so that you learn smth new.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a = [4, 5, 35, 23, 16, 7, 12]
b = ['john', 'joe', 'Pier', 'Paul', 'Moe', 'Jane', 'Ruth']
c = []

for x,y in zip(a, b):
    m = {'label':y, 'value':x}
    c.append(m)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[{'label': 'john', 'value': 4}, {'label': 'joe', 'value': 5}, {'label': 'Pier', 'value': 35}, {'label': 'Paul', 'value': 23}, {'label': 'Moe', 'value': 16}, {'label': 'Jane', 'value': 7}, {'label': 'Ruth', 'value': 12}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listofdicts = [{'label':j,'value':i} for i,j in zip(valuevalues,labelvalues)]
```

The labels and values list is redundant.

Comment: Didn't realize someone else posted the same answer lol.